# Adding a like button to a post that doesn't refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I am trying to add a like button to a post in my RoR application. The two models I have are `Post` and `Like`.

On my webpage I am going to put the like button right next to the post button, but when users click the like button, I would like to have th request run in the background and not have to refresh the page.

Does anyone know of a simple way I could do this or where I can learn more about how to do it?

I am using the jQuery JavaScript library in my Rails application.

Comment: Sorry I just have no experience with Javascript or AJAX what so ever, so I'm not really sure what to do to make my question more specific.

Comment: Well, study jQuery's ajax, try to make it work... If you have any problem, we're here to help. With some code, your question will be much more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery's ajax

api here

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

or even this one

http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.ajax

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery, you should use the jQuery.ajax() method, or one of it's deriviatives depending on your purposes. It runs in the background, and is very easy to use.